# What's the best way to revive JSON dates in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

When doing

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

dates are transformed to strings. What's the best way, performance wise, to revive them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a jsperf benchmark with three different ways here: http://jsperf.com/json-parse-date-reviver

The quickest out of those three seems to be:

```
JSON.parse(obj, function(name, value) {
    if (typeof value === "string" && /^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\dZ$/.test(value)) {
        return new Date(value);
    }
    return value;
});
```